# Including basics library of C (unistd.h) on window

Tags: c, shell, unix, windows-10

I've been programming at my school on a Mac for one month. We did C programming on an UNIX shell.

Now i'm back at home and I use my own PC that is on window 10. I have tried to make a similar set up, but i don't know much about all that. I installed git and bash, this made it like a UNIX shell. Also I have installed the gcc compiler.

So, now that i'm making a basic program, it should be working but when I make the `include <unistd.h>`, the shell can't find it.

I know my question is probably silly but I really couldn't find how to solve the problem. I downloaded the unistd.h file.

I also found this http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Compiler/diagnostic_messages/5

It explain that i should be putting the .h folder in some kind of defined path, but I don't know how to do that.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Headers like `unistd.h` are standard POSIX system headers. Windows is *not* a POSIX system, however. It has its own API and set of headers.

Comment: Having said that, all is not lost. You can always install a Linux distro on a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and have yourself access to such a development environment.

Comment: I even recommend installing a Linux distribution on your personal laptop (with, or perhaps even instead of, Windows)

Comment: I am not sure it is possible for me to install a virtual machine. I tried it a long time ago and my pc was not strong enough. I thought downloading the unistd.h file would be enough to make it work

Comment: A totally different approach to trying to make Windows look like Linux is to install Visual Studio and use *that* for programming on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed gcc as part of mingw or something similar, it should have included a unistd.h.  Just having the gcc compiler is not likely to get you very far.

You probably want to start over and install something different than you did ([mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or just set up a vm as suggested) that provides a more complete environment.

Comment: Well the git bash, that i installed, open a shell wich is called mingw64 ( i guess i downloaded 2 differents thing in one ). So it's probably already installed the good way (if not, no problem to start over).

So it should already had included the unistd.h ? Maybe i'm doing it wrong then, i thought that writting #include <unistd.h> would make him find the good path automaticly

Comment: in your question, explain what you downloaded and what you did to install it, and show the program you are trying to compile, how you are trying to compile it, and what errors you receive.

Comment: Ok sorry.
First i did downloaded git bash, just to use github. But it came with a unix shell. https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then i downloaded gcc  when i saw that i could not compile, it installed itself alone without asking me path or anything, and the git shell could then compile.  https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/?source=typ_redirect

And at the end, as the file unistd.h could not be found in my #include <unistd.h>, i downloaded it, but it's no use because i don't know where to put it for the shell to use it.